# CVV Code For Authorize.com using osCommerce

Tags: oscommerce, authorize.net

Hi I need to add a CVV code for verifying credit cards upon check out on my osCommerece shopping cart. I think this will involve a code for the authorize.net php and the checkout processing php but not sure.

[Found this great write up](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Validating-Credit-Card-Information-Part-3-of-3-CVV-Numbers/ba-p/7657), but it is only for the authorize.net php and it doesn't create a filed for the CVV to be keyed. Also it throws an error with the 'echo validate.' Can't seem to find anything in any forums for osCommerce or any place out.

Hoping someone here will have some knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out an authorize.net developer account. You can use sandbox mode. I found a post there that is similar to your question.

http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Is-there-a-way-to-test-CVV-amp-AVS-with-my-Sandbox-account/td-p/8009